# Why logPurchase event in firereact-native-firebase/analytics return empty price value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I have installed this library for my react-native project and it works fine, but when I use `logPurchase` event it firebase table price always is 0. I also tried to add hardcoded value but it also doesnt't work. So what's going wrong? Because I can't fine any solution.

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

async sendPurchaseAnalytics() {
    const { order} = this.state;
    const tax = order?.data?.totalRevenue - order?.data?.totalExclTax;
    const items = order?.products.map(product => {
        return {
            item_brand: product?.vendorName,
            item_id: product?.prodlevid,
            item_name: product?.name,
            price: +product?.sprice,
            quantity: product?.quantity,
        }
    })

    await analytics().logPurchase({
        value: +order?.total,
        currency: 'euro',
        tax: +tax?.toFixed(2),
        items,
    }); 
}
```

But `Item revenue` column is always 0;

[this is image from analytics.google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n8wR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revenue events such as [purchase](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#purchase) require you to set the currency if you will set a value for revenue metrics to be computed accurately, so ensure that you are sending those two parameters together. From your code implementation, it seems like you're using 'euro' for the currency parameter. Which I believe, cause your revenue metrics not to show up. You must supply a [3-letter ISO_4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217?utm_source=developers.google.com&utm_medium=referral#Active_codes) currency code in the currency parameter. For Euros currency, you must use the code 'EUR'. See this [list](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7007736?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#zippy=%2Cin-this-article:%7E:text=Supported%20currencies%20and%20codes) for the supported currencies and codes in Firebase.